# How to bend only selected vertices?

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow, geometry

I have the following problem which I do not know how to resolve by using blender.

I want to bend a bit of an object but I don't know how to achieve this result by just selecting few faces and not the entire object.

Below there is an image to explain myself better:

[image: Example]

How can I do this?
Also, is it posible bending just by using Y/X axis blocking the Z axis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The [Bend Tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/deforming/bend.html) can be used to do what you are trying to achieve.  Select the components  you want to bend, position the 3D cursor at the point where the bend will pivot then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

[image]

Comment: You might want to include details about position of mouse cursor relatively to 3D cursor while bending.

Comment: That's all in the linked documentation.

Comment: See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). The main reason for elaborating in your answers here on SE is allowing future readers not to go through links and read what you expected them to understand. Provide them with quotes / summary of link along with it.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can also use the

### Simple Deform Modifier

The control of size and angle of the bended mesh is a good advantage.

The *Bend* deformation of the *Modifier* bends the mesh over the Z axis.
It's advisable to add a new *Object* and join it to the other *Object* after setting up and applying the **Simple Deform Modifier**

---

### 1. Add *Edge Loops*

- In *Edit Mode* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Hover the mouse over the desired position. A pink *Edge Loop* appears. 
  Use the mouse wheel to determine the number of *Edge Loops*.
- Confirm with <kbd>LMB</kbd>

[image: add Edge Loops]

---

### 2. Positioning of *3D Cursor*

- Select the vertices where your 'curve' should start to bend.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and choose *Cursor to Selected*.

[image: positioning 3D Cursor]

---

### 3. Add *Empty* and **Simple Deform Modifier**

- In *Object Mode* press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to add an *Empty* at the *3D Cursor*.
- Select the object and go to the *Modifier* Tab. Add the **Simple Deform Modifier**.
- You have the choice of four deform methods. Click on *Bend*.
- Choose the Empty as the *Origin* of the deformation.
- Select your desired *Angle*.

[image: Add Empty and Modifier]

---

#### Now You can adjust the *Empty*:

- Rotate to control the axis.
- Translate to control the origin of deformation.
- Scale to change the deform factor.

  [image: adjust]

  *Scaling and translation on Z axes has no influence with these settings*

---

**Note:**
In Your case the bended Object need the right Position and Rotation to join it with original Object. You can achieve this easily with [**Copy Attributes Menu**](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu) *Add-on*

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to use **Proportional Editing**.

You can determine the shape by selecting a type of "Falloff from the dropdown menue (In this example I used **Sharp**).

[image]

Select the top vertices ,or any appropriate vertices.

Press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab them a circle will then appear around your cursor. The size of this circle is controlled by your mouse wheel and determines how many additional vertices are affected.

Pressing <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd> will constrain the direction to that axis.

[image]

While still using proportional editing, you can also make use of your 3D cursor location to base the origin of your rotation off of it, instead of your default location.

[image: Proportional Editing Constrained to 3D Cursor]